# Is there a way to make chrome extension activated only in incognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'd like to ask if there's a way to make chrome extension ONLY activated in incognito mode.

I only want the extension activated in incognito mode and disabled in normal browsing.

I do hope there's a way and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You can't do exactly this.

Closest way is to create a separate Chrome Profile and install extensions there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but for that you require Opera Browser. Activating Extensions Only in Incognito is not possible in Chrome, Switch to Opera.